# Bending a horizontal from 0 to infinity real number line, ninety degress counter-clickwise at 1.

Tags: arithmetic, analytic-geometry

Can the real number line from 0 to infinity, which of course is often represented as a horizontal straight line, also be represented as being bent ninety degrees counter-clockwise at 1? I.e., if such a straight real number line representation is bent that way, does it remain a legitimate alternate representation of the real number line from 0 to infinity?

The reason that I ask includes the possibly pedagogically useful fact that, by doing so, lines connecting reciprocals (such as lines connecting 1/2 to 2, and 1/3 to 3, etc., which are usually not too well visually distinguished when such lines share a straight horizontal number line from 0 to infinity) can be readily distinguished when instead the unit line segment [0,1] is seen as the horizontal part of a real number line, and the rest of the real numbers from 1 to infinity are represented on the vertical part. The real numbers conisting of 0 and an infinite set of pairs of reciprocals also becomes more visually apparent, as well as some other properties.

Comment: As a visual representation the number line has little to no mathematical value (A "line" can be defined mathematically as a set of points so it's not entirely useless) so yes you can represent it any way you want.  On conventional xy play you are plotting the lines  (y-1/n) = n(n-1)(x-1).  No reason you can't do that.

Comment: Much thanks. And your answer prompts another question if you do not mind... Whatvstopd us from saying the first point greater than 0 is 1/inf? And then saying that next comes 2/inf, then 3/inf.... inf/inf? And as a result, having the 0 to 1 unit line segment expressed that way?